# How to modify Browsable API form

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Currently, I am creating a UserRegistration view, which should display form with password/confirm password fields. The problem is that the Browsable API displays only fields which occur in the model's definition.

- How should I tweak the form so that to be able to add custom fields?

  ```
  class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      password = serializers.CharField(
          max_length=128,
          widget=widgets.PasswordInput,
          label=_('Password')
      )
      password_confirm = serializers.CharField(
          max_length=128,
          widget=widgets.PasswordInput,
          label=_('Confirm password')
      )

      class Meta:
          model = User
          fields = ('id', 'name', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'registration_date')

      def validate(self, attrs):
          if attrs.get('password') and attrs.get('password_confirm'):
              if attrs['password'] != attrs['password_confirm']:
                  raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Passwords do not match"))
          return attrs
  ```
- Also, what is the best way to distinguish the input serializer from the output serializer?

Answer (score 0):

Well first you'd want to define this in the `View` or `ViewSet` that you're using. The serializer doesn't control the browsable API in that way, it just handles taking objects from native to some serialized format and back.

Since you don't mention, I'm going to guess you're using http://django-rest-framework.org/

The specific part of documentation you may want to check out is: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets.html#modelviewset

Answer (score 0):

Django Rest Framework actually uses normal Django Forms that are rendered into the Browsable API view.

You can control the look of the form by modifying the Renderer that is used: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers#browsableapirenderer

For example:

```
class MyBrowsableAPIRenderer(BrowsableAPIRenderer):
    # either
    def get_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyBrowsableAPIRenderer, self).get_context(*args, **kwargs)
        context["post_form"] = django.form.Form()  # modify form here          

    # or
    def get_rendered_html_form(self, view, method, request):
        # do things here to create full Form

@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer, MyBrowsableAPIRenderer)):
    class MyViewSet(GenericViewSet):
        pass
```

I do not know if you can modify a Form after it has been created, I haven't tried. If not, you could rewrite the entire function that creates the form. I you could add Form fields, that would be preferable.