# How to set a custom form for an API view using the Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm looking to set a form that inherits from django forms on an a view. I'm using the django rest framework. Here's my code so far:

```
class MyView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):

        # ... do stuff ...
```

I want to render this form for the get method for MyView

```
class XyzForm(forms.Form):
    x = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    y = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    z = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
```

Comment: Update the question with version numbers for Django and DRF.

Comment: Django 1.7.1 & DRF 3.0.0

Comment: DRF maps the form fields automatically, so no go with defining your own custom form class. You should instead create new serializer (inherit) and use it in your view with html form rendering.

Comment: Can you give an end goal of what you want to accomplish? Are you just trying to post data through the rest framework?

Answer (score 3):

In this question I showed how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782251/django-rest-framework-serializer-as-a-form-in-get-deprecated

Not very satisfied with my solution yet (hence my question), but it works.

Not sure why... but above was removed (abandonded question... according to the communituy....) the code might help others and this question:

I just upgarde to django rest framework (DRF) version 2.4.4 (as a step before upgrading to 3.0.2, I came from 2.3.6)

and I got some problem with showing a form in the browsable api.

The method I use is GET to get a list, I'll explain my method in version 2.3.6 (which worked):
I used to use a serializer as a form to filter some of the data. The returned value is done with the modelserializer.
The filter is very far related to the list, and not by models definitions, so using the build in filter system is not (yet) an option to me.

I found out, through other questions, it is related that the form is not shown when using get method (only put, post and patch). e.g. this question was very helpfull:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487471/how-to-modify-browsable-api-form?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782251/django-rest-framework-serializer-as-a-form-in-get-deprecated)

this used to be my code (works fine in DRF 2.3.6):

let's say this is the serializer for the form:

```
class SomeSerializerForm(serializers.Serializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=17)
    field2 = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
```

and this is the serializer for the returned data:

```
class MyModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = MyModel
       depth = 1
```

than this was my api view:

```
class SomeApiView(GenericAPIView):
    permissions = (IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = SomeSerializerForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializerform = self.get_serializer(data=request.DATA)
        if not serializerform.is_valid():
            raise ParseError(detail="No valid values")
        field1 = request.DATA['field1']
        field2 = request.DATA['field2']
        myObjects=MyObject.objects.filter(some filter based on the fields and some extra functions above)
        serializer = MyModelSerializer(myObjects,many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

this worked perfectly (code was a bit adjusted of course, but this was the thing basiclaly)

but after upgrade this does not work anymore...

I found some hack to get the form in the get again, using:

let's say I create this form:

and use this in my own renderer:

```
class SomeApiForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.CharField(max_length=17,help_text='help text with form 1')
    field2 = forms.IntegerField(required=False,help_text='another help text')


class MyBrowsableAPIRenderer(BrowsableAPIRenderer):
    def get_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyBrowsableAPIRenderer, self).get_context(*args, **kwargs)
        context['display_edit_forms'] = True
        form = SomeApiForm()
        context['post_form'] = form 
        return context
```

this works again the way it used to do.... but

Now I Am looking for a more generic way...

using the form = SomeApiForm() means I have to create a renderer class for every api... (so it works after some puzzling... but it's not a nice solution in my point of view)

but htis was my question... or at least the part before I formulated my question:

Comment: Question not found, clicking on that link.

Comment: yep, not sure why it was removed by the community,  but I could still open it... so copy pasted it in here for you.